# Abbreviation for 'mid-week' in French

Tags: indications-de-temps, abréviations

I'm making a spreadsheet which will have column headers that indicate mid-week and week end days that look like this:

Mid | Sat | Sun

In my mind I could translate this as:

Mil | Sam | Dim

But would this make any sense to an actual french person? Would 'Mil' be confusing? Should I insert a full stop to show it's an abbreviation? (e.g. Mil.)

Google says midweek is translated as 'milieu de la semaine' which is way too long. Even though it's kinda longer than desired I would be fine with 'Milieu' in the spreadsheet if that would be understood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Mil* or even *milieu de semaine* wouldn't be understood in France if you mean the period from Monday to Thursday. One of the reasons is that period of time is not considered to be in the middle of the week by the majority of French people, the first day of the week being Monday for the most of us. *Milieu de semaine* means Wednesday or around Wednesday (Tuesday to Thursday) in French.

You might use:

> lun-ven | sam | dim

or

> semaine | sam | dim

An official name for the five working days is *jours ouvrés* but *semaine* (especially in the expression *en semaine*) is common.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm going  to go with 'lun-ven' as it's unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, "during the week", "in the week" or just "the week" are most common in English (UK) too ...